# How does flow use with react native and option 'all=true'?

Tags: react-native, flowtype

I want use option 'all=true'. But I don't want to parse node_modules folder.

But I receive an error: Cannot resolve module react-native.

My config:

```
[ignore]
.*/node_modules/*

[include]

[libs]

[lints]

[options]
all=true

[strict]

[untyped]
.*/node_modules/react-native
```

Another config (doesn't work too):

```
[ignore]
.*/node_modules/*

[include]

[libs]

[lints]

[options]
module.system.node.resolve_dirname=node_modules
all=true

[strict]

[untyped]
.*/node_modules/react-native
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> This is different from the [ignore] config section that causes matching files to be ignored by the module resolver, which inherently makes them un-typechecked, and also unresolvable by import or require.
>
> https://flow.org/en/docs/config/untyped/

By putting `.*/node_modules/*` in the `[ignore]` section of your flow configuration, you are preventing Flow from resolving the module. You can solve this by either removing the `node_modules` directory from the `[ignore]` section (or just the `react-native` package if you want to keep ignoring other node modules), or by creating a `[libs]` entry for `react-native`. I would recommend not ignoring all node modules as this will cause issues for Flow for every module import.

Comment: I do not understand how to solve this problem. If I remove it. * / Node_modules / *, then I get errors like https://pastebin.com/M9dzuPff

My new config:
[ignore]

[include]

[libs]

[lints]

[options]
all=true

[strict]

Comment: Looks like `react-native` has a [template `.flowconfig`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/template/_flowconfig) that you should follow. Seems like your problems might go away with the `[ignore]` section targeting `.*/*[.]android.js`.

Comment: How did you create your project? I used `npx react-native init AwesomeProject` and, after installing `flow-bin`, running the `flow` command completed without errors.

Comment: Have you added the option add=true?

Answer (score 0):

In the ignore, you can mark some dirs or files to exclude from the ignore with the `!` symbol.

I've created a PR to add it to flow docs that will explain it a bit more, but waiting on merge. https://github.com/facebook/flow/pull/8360/files

```
[ignore]
.*/node_modules/*
!*/node_modules/react-native/.*

[include]

[libs]

[lints]

[options]
all=true

[strict]
```

But as user11307804 mentioned, you'll get unresolved errors for all other deps because all your other dependencies will be unresolvable since you've ignored them.

At which point you should use https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed which will fill in all the blanks for your dependency tree by either pulling from community defined types or stubbing them.

The reason `react-native` is treated differently is because it's one of the few dependencies that is flowtyped inside the library itself as opposed to being maintained in the flow-typed community package.

As you find more packages you use that are flowtyped internally you can add them to the list of packages to exclude from ignoring.